# awk to filter file using another capturing all instances

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` I am trying to capture all conditions of`KCNMA1`, the line in `gene` (which is a one column list of names) that are in `$8` of `file` which is `tab-delimited`

So in the below example all instances/lines where `KCNMA1` appear in `$8`would be printed to `output`.

There could also be multiple `;`, however the name, in this case `KCNMA1` will be included. The `awk` seems to capture 2 of the possible 4 conditions but not all instances as shown by the current output. Thank you :).

**gene**

```
KCNMA1
```

**file**

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.IDP.refGene    Gene.IDP.refGene    GeneDetail.IDP.refGene
4629    chr10   78944590    78944590    G   A   intergenic  NONE;KCNMA1 dist=NONE;dist=451371
4630    chr10   79396463    79396463    C   T   intronic    KCNMA1  .
4631    chr10   79397777    79397777    C   -   exonic  KCNMA1;X1X  .
4632    chr10   81318663    81318663    C   G   exonic  SFTPA2  .
4633    chr10   89397777    89397777    -   GAA exonic  NONE;X1X;KCNMA1 .
```

current output

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.IDP.refGene    Gene.IDP.refGene    GeneDetail.IDP.refGene
1   chr10   79396463    79396463    C   T   intronic    KCNMA1  .
2   chr10   79397777    79397777    C   -   exonic  KCNMA1;X1X  .
```

**desired output** (`tab-delimeted`)

```
 R_Index    Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.IDP.refGene    Gene.IDP.refGene    GeneDetail.IDP.refGene
4629    chr10   78944590    78944590    G   A   intergenic  NONE;KCNMA1 dist=NONE;dist=451371
4630    chr10   79396463    79396463    C   T   intronic    KCNMA1  .
4631    chr10   79397777    79397777    C   -   exonic  KCNMA1;X1X  .
4633    chr10   89397777    89397777    -   GAA exonic  NONE;X1X;KCNMA1 .
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} FNR==1{print} {x=$8; sub(/;.*/,"",x)} x in a{$1=++c; print}' gene file > out
```

Comment: Not sure why the`-1`, thought i included all details, but edited.  Thank you :).

Comment: I think this works for you: awk 'NR<2;$8~/KCNMA1/' file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the single gene, just pass as a variable

```
$ awk -v gene='KCNMA1' -v d=';' 'NR==1 || d $8 d ~ d gene d' file
```

the counter you're using seems unnecessary since you want to have the first field.

If you want to support a file based gene list, you can use this

```
$ awk -v d=';' 'NR==FNR {genes[$0]; next} 
                FNR==1; 
                        {for(g in genes) 
                           if(d $8 d ~ d g d) print}' genes file
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So is all text in each line of `gene`read into an array `g` and the `d=;` tells `awk` that a `;` may be in each line. If it is just  look for any string in array `g` in `$8` of `file`. I apologize if my understanding is off, i am trying to learn.  Thank you very much :)

Comment: it's to eliminate substring matches, for example assume you were looking for "CNMA", you don't want to match with KCNMA1.  This may not be a problem for your data set, but better to be safe.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot :).